# Don't analyze pods in Xcode

Tags: xcode, cocoapods

I have xcworkspace created by cocoapods. When I'm building my target app, Xcode tells me warnings about code in the used pods. Same thing with Analyse tool, it inspects pod's code too. Is it possible to avoid analysing (both deep and swallow) for pods project?

I thought this should be configured in the schemes, but there is no actions for the pods schemes, and in the my target scheme there is no pods configuration.
Also I've checked pods project and target settings, and sure that `analyse during build` is set to `No`.

**UPD 14sep14**:
Is there also any way to ignore issues of cocoapods build system? 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The reason Xcode inspects the pod code, is because that code will be submitted along with your app. If your pod has warnings, you could fix them and create a pull request for the library you are using. If you're not sure how to fix the warnings, just post the warnings as an issue (as long as the issue doesn't already exist).

If you decide that you really want to ignore the warnings you can add the following to your Podfile.

```
inhibit_all_warnings!
```

Comment: Yeah, I've commited that to upstream and waited over two months, which is uncomfortable long way to fix warnings. And I had to even change git url in the podfile, so after my changes were merged I have to roll back the Podfile.

Comment: ok, code issues now gone, but internal cocoapod tool issues are still there. I have updated the question. Do you know easy way to supress them?